# This task is currently locked by a running workflow and cannot be edited

Tags: workflow

I'm getting an error on my workflow task (custom workflow with custom task page). Its been working without any problems for a while. 
 The workflow states Completed but the associated task is not completed. I've noticed the task percent complete is equal to 101. Dont know if this is has anything to do with problem.

I've found some resources that talk about too many workflows running or custom task forms.
 http://geekswithblogs.net/JayantSharma/archive/2012/07/02/this-task-is-currently-locked-by-a-running-workflow-and.aspx

Does anyone have any experience on this issue ?

I've looked at the log files:

```
    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: This task is currently locked by a running workflow and cannot be edited.   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.PrepareItemForUpdate(SPWeb web, Boolean bMigration, Boolean& bAdd, Boolean& bPublish, Object& objAttachmentNames, Object& objAttachmentContents, Int32& parentFolderId)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.UpdateInternal(Boolean bSystem, Boolean bPreserveItemVersion, Guid newGuidOnAdd, Boolean bMigration, Boolean bPublish, Boolean bNoVersion, Boolean bCheckOut, Boolean bCheckin, Boolean suppressAfterEvents, String filename)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem.Update()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowTask.AlterTask(SPListItem task, Hashtable htData, Boolean fSynchronous)    
 at MonitorCard.btnEndMonitor_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint
```

UPDATE:
In SP Manager I located the task that failed to close. This is part of XML field:
ows_owshiddenversion='21' ows_WorkflowVersion='512' ows_*UIVersion='512' ows*_UIVersionString='1.0' ows_Attachments='0'

Can i edit here and change ows_WorkflowVersion='512' to ows_WorkflowVersion='1' ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the Update statement.

```
`task[SPBuiltInFieldId.WorkflowVersion] = 1;`
`task.SystemUpdate();`
```

Comment: Hi Where do I put the Update statement? The list has a custom workflow running and there are several instances already running of workflow. I dont want to update and re-deploy the workflow. Is this powershell script ?  Can you supply more info pls?

Comment: Hi ALi, Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange. While your answer may answer the question it lacks extra content, please refer to the [FAQ][1] for more information on how to post here. [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq